# Перевод времени комментария на Великий и могучий

Tags: php, wordpress

Здравствуйте, хэшкодовцы.

Я решил поставить на сайт один вордпрессовский шаблон. И возникла такая (возможно, стандартная) проблема. Когда оставляешь комментарий, он отсчитывает, когда был сделан этот комментарий, и выводит: "1 seconds ago, 2 seconds ago... 1 hour, 2 hours и т.д."

А я хочу перевести это на русский язык. Но проблема в том, что в нашем языке все не так просто. В исходном коде просто склеивается minut и s, если число отличается от единицы. А у нас должно быть:

- 1 минута
- 2 минуты
- 5 минут
- 1 час
- 2 часа
- 5 часов

Короче, куча условий. Как бы это все дело укоротить? Может, кто знает, какие методы применить в php. Просто я с пыхой не очень дружу, ибо я верстальщик. Более-менее еще знаю jQuery.
Исходный код прилагаю. Буду рад любой помощи.

---

```
function pp_ago($timestamp){
   $difference = time() - $timestamp;
   $periods = array("second", "minute", "hour", "day", "week", "month", "year", "decade");
   $lengths = array("60","60","24","7","4.35","12","10");
   for($j = 0; $difference >= $lengths[$j]; $j++)
   $difference /= $lengths[$j];
   $difference = round($difference);
   if($difference != 1) $periods[$j].= "s";
   $text = "$difference $periods[$j] ago";
   return $text;
}
```

---

Comment: Начните с изучения ответов на вопрос о [склонении слов на PHP](http://hashcode.ru/questions/215279#215315)

Answer (score 1):

Простой пример, усложнять по мере необходимости

http://pastebin.com/C7UU1GTa

```
<?php
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Moscow');
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');

/**
* @param array $titles - массив названий вида ['час', 'часа', 'часов']
* @return string
*/
function declensionByNumber($number, array $titles) {
    $cases = array(2, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2);
    return $titles[($number % 100 > 4 && $number % 100 < 20) ? 2 : $cases[($number % 10 < 5) ? $number % 10 : 5]];
}

/**
* @return string
*/
function formatInterval(DateInterval $interval) {
    $dictionary = [
            [ 'y', ['год', 'года', 'лет']],
            [ 'm', ['месяц', 'месяца', 'месяцев']],
            [ 'd', ['день', 'дня', 'дней']],
            [ 'h', ['час', 'часа', 'часов']],
            [ 'i', ['минута', 'минуты', 'минут']],
            [ 's', ['секунда', 'секунды', 'секунд']]
        ];
    $description_array = [];

    foreach($dictionary as $item) {
        list($key, $variants) = $item;

        $digit = $interval->{$key};
        if($key != 's' && $digit == 0) {
            continue;
        }
        $description_array[] = sprintf('%d %s', $digit, declensionByNumber($digit, $variants));
    }

    return implode(' ', $description_array);
}

$now = new DateTime;
$then = new DateTime('- 1 month - 22 days - 13 hours - 35 seconds');

$interval = $now->diff($then);

?>
От: <?= $now->format('Y-m-d H:i:s') ?><br>
До: <?= $then->format('Y-m-d H:i:s') ?><br>
Интервал: <?= formatInterval($interval) ?><br>
```

Answer (score 0):

Вообще всего три варианта написания на каждое слово в зависимости от цифр на конце.

1. окончание на 1: секунду, минуту, час
2. окончание на 2-4: секунды, минуты, часа
3. окончание на 5-0: секунд, минут, часов
4. исключение для окончания на 11-14, тут так же как и 5-0: секунд, минут, часов